# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' with django 1.10.5

Tags: mysql, django

I am facing this error when calling `python manage.py migrate`
for the first time.I am in windows. Installed mysql, created database, put the database name as well.
The `django version is 1.10.5`,**python version** i am using is `python 3.7`, but `python 2.7` is also in the system.
Some of the solutions say that the visual studio developer tools might fix the problem, I installed the visual stdio 2017 developer tools, still The problem is persisting.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_
from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_c
lass
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "I:\python projects\Virtual_Environments\todo_project_venv\todo_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Comment: But did you install the mysqldb library?

Comment: I figured out , i had to install mysqlclient, it took me 3 days

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, I had to install a specific version of `mysqlclient` to resolve these errors.

I had to **uninstall** `python 3.7`(possibly there are some issues, I observed).

then installed `python 3.6.5.`

then installed `mysqlclient 1.3.12`

These two don't conflict and project is running smoothly.